# How to convert time stamp in Python from dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss:msmsms to yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:msmsmsmsmsms

Tags: python, date, variables, timestamp, date-conversion

I have created an automated data client that pulls data from a txt file and inputs it into a csv file. Each data entry contains a timestamp, but it is not in the format I need it in, I need it to match the datetime.now() format:

**ORIGINAL FORMAT** [03/11/22 01:06:09:190]

**DESIRED FORMAT** 2022-11-03 01:06:09.190000

I am currently using the following code to pull the timestamp from each line of data I need:
82:     reTimestamp = r'\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}'

```
105:     for line in f:
106:         line.strip()
108:     timestamp = re.findall(reTimestamp, line.strip())

110: print(timestamp)
```

---

Output: ['03/11/22 01:05:06:172']

Every function is working well up until now because im having trouble converting this timestamp to the desired format. I would also like to get rid of the square brackets '[]'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `timestamp` is a list, to access the string try `timestamp[0]`

And you can convert the string to your desired datetime format using the below code

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = ['03/11/22 01:05:06:172']
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(timestamp[0], '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S:%f')
date_time = datetime_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
date_time
#Output: 2022-11-03 01:05:06.172000
```

Comment: This worked fine thank you, but the output is 22-11-03 01:05:06.172000 (The year format is different) any recommendations on how to get 2022

Comment: In that case you can use a lowercase 'y' i.e. `%y` for the year.

You can check the format codes from the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes)

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets mean it is a list. You can get rid of them by selecting the first item in the list:

```
print(timestamp[0])
```

As for the date conversions, use the built-in [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) package